# Parsing response in Python

Tags: python, httprequest, httpresponse

Im having trouble parsing through my response in python, any feedback on what I need to change is appreciated!

```
url = 'https://someURL'
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer <MyToken>'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#This part prints entire response content in a text like format [{'x':'' ,'y':'', ...etc},{'x':'' ,'y':'', ...etc},...etc]

jsonResponse = r.json()
print("Entire JSON response")
print(jsonResponse)

# when I try to parse into each item and get the key value, I get an error
print("Print each key-value pair from JSON response")
for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
    print(key, ":", value)
```

> This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blueiInitialSync.py", line 131, in <module>
    for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

Also this is what I see in debug mode when drilling into `r`
[image]

Comment: `jsonResponse` is of type `list`. Try `for key, value in jsonResponse[0].items():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over a list of dicts not just a dict. You need to unpack each dict in the list.

```
for d in jsonResponse:
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(key, ":", value)
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked! I have a follow up question, in the above code Im hardcoding my bearer token that I'm getting by doing a postman call...Im not sure how to do the actual post request in python, Ive done it in javascript like so                                                                   ``` var options = {method: 'POST',url: 'https://myurl',qs:{grant_type: 'client_credentials', client_id: 'xyz',client_secret: 'abc'},
headers:
 {'cache-control': 'no-cache'}};``` but Im having trouble with doing the same in python.

Comment: @CatGirl19 This seems like another question topic. Post another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a list of dictionaries, when you run "for" on the list it runs once for every dictionary. To print the dictionaries individually, example;

```
list_of_dict = [{"a": 5, "b": 10},{"c": 15, "d": 20}]
for i in list_of_dict:
    print(i)
```

Will print out,

{'a': 5, 'b': 10}

{'c': 15, 'd': 20}